# Creating default object from empty value (Laravel)

Tags: sql, foreach, laravel-8

I need to insert filenames into columns (image1, ..., image5) for selected row ($id). Uploading to FTP works fine, but I can't update the database due to an error "Creating default object from empty value". What should I have changed?

**Controller**

```
public function packshotsupdate(Request $request, $id){

        $pim_product = pim_product::where('id', $id)->first();
        
                

        $companyGroup = Session::get('loginId');
        if($companyGroup == 1){
            $sortByCompany = "a";
        }elseif($companyGroup == 2){
            $sortByCompany = "b";
        }else{
            $sortByCompany = "";
        }

            $getBrandSKUid = rand(1,1000000);
   

            if($request->hasFile('filenames')){
                $i = 0;
                $numeracja = 1;
                
                  foreach($request->file('filenames') as $key => $file)
                    {
                        $name = $getBrandSKUid.'-'.$i++.'.'.$file->extension();
                        $file->move(public_path('uploads/'.str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($sortByCompany)).'/'), $name);  
                        $files[] = $name;
        
            
                        $packshot = 'image'.$numeracja++;
                        $pim_product->$packshot = 'uploads/'.str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($sortByCompany)).'/'.$name;
                     
                    }
        
                }

        $res = $pim_product->update();
        
        if($res){
            return redirect(route('change_packshots', ['locale' => app()->getLocale() == 'en'? 'en':'pl', 'id'=>$id]))->with('success', 'Pomyślnie zaktualizowano zdjęcia produktowe.');
        }else{
            return redirect(route('change_packshots', ['locale' => app()->getLocale() == 'en'? 'en':'pl', 'id'=>$id]))->with('fail', 'Wystąpił błąd.');
        }

    }
```

**Controller - part of the function "displayPackshots"**

```
if(is_null($company['image1']) || $company['image1'] == ''){
                        echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image1" name="filenames[0]">
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="image1">Packshot 1</label>
                    </div>';
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="image1x"><a href="'.route('deletephoto', ['locale' => app()->getLocale() == 'en'? 'en':'pl', 'id'=>$company['id'], 'count'=>'1', 'brand'=>$company['modifiedby'], 'filename'=>$packshot1file]).'"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line></svg></a></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image1x" name="image1x" value="'.$company['image1'].'" disabled>
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="image1x">Packshot 1</label>
                </div>';
                }
                if(is_null($company['image2']) || $company['image2'] == ''){
                        echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image2" name="filenames[1]">
                            <label class="input-group-text" for="image2">Packshot 2</label>
                        </div>';
                } else {
                        echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="image2x"><a href="'.route('deletephoto', ['locale' => app()->getLocale() == 'en'? 'en':'pl', 'id'=>$company['id'], 'count'=>'2', 'brand'=>$company['modifiedby'], 'filename'=>$packshot2file]).'"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line></svg></a></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image2x" name="image2x" value="'.$company['image2'].'" disabled>
                        <label class="input-group-text" for="image2x">Packshot 2</label>
                    </div>';
                }
                if(is_null($company['image3']) || $company['image3'] == ''){
                    echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image3" name="filenames[2]">
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="image3">Packshot 3</label>
                    </div>';
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="image3x"><a href="'.route('deletephoto', ['locale' => app()->getLocale() == 'en'? 'en':'pl', 'id'=>$company['id'], 'count'=>'3', 'brand'=>$company['modifiedby'], 'filename'=>$packshot3file]).'"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line></svg></a></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image3x" name="image3x" value="'.$company['image3'].'" disabled>
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="image3x">Packshot 3</label>
                </div>';
                }
                if(is_null($company['image4']) || $company['image4'] == ''){
                    echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image4" name="filenames[3]">
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="image4">Packshot 4</label>
                    </div>';
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="image4x"><a href="'.route('deletephoto', ['locale' => app()->getLocale() == 'en'? 'en':'pl', 'id'=>$company['id'], 'count'=>'4', 'brand'=>$company['modifiedby'], 'filename'=>$packshot4file]).'"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line></svg></a></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image4x" name="image4x" value="'.$company['image4'].'" disabled>
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="image4x">Packshot 4</label>
                </div>';
                }
                if(is_null($company['image5']) || $company['image5'] == ''){
                    echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image5" name="filenames[4]">
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="image5">Packshot 5</label>
                    </div>';
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="image5x"><a href="'.route('deletephoto', ['locale' => app()->getLocale() == 'en'? 'en':'pl', 'id'=>$company['id'], 'count'=>'5', 'brand'=>$company['modifiedby'], 'filename'=>$packshot5file]).'"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line></svg></a></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image5x" name="image5x" value="'.$company['image5'].'" disabled>
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="image5x">Packshot 5</label>
                </div>';
                }
```

**Blade**

```
<form action="{{ route('packshotsupdate', ['locale' => app()->getLocale() == 'en'? 'en':'pl', 'id'=>request()->route('id')]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <h3 class="mt-5 mb-5">Zarządzanie zdjęciami produktowymi</h3>
    {{ App\Http\Controllers\PIM::displayPackshots(); }}
  <button type="submit" class="mt-5 btn btn-lg btn-green">Zapisz</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What code specifically is triggering that error?

Comment: $pim_product->$packshot = 'uploads/'.str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($sortByCompany)).'/'.$name;

Comment: You likely have an extra `$` after the `$`: `$pim_product->$packshot` should be `$pim_product->packshot`. Variables can be used as Array/Object index or key, but `$packshot` is not defined, so `->$packshot` triggers that rather vague error. Easy fix as `->packshot` 

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution still gives the same error.

Comment: Well, that can happen if this query returns `null`: `$pim_product = pim_product::where('id', $id)->first();`. Maybe use `->firstOrFail()`, or short curcuit via `if (!$pim_product) { abort(404); }` `null->packshot` is just as bad as `$pim_product->$packshot`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was related to $id. This variable have not provided an expected value, so the script did not know which row should be updated. By the way. Can you please tell me how to modify foreach if I want to get the data from input 1 and save the record to column image 1 etc.?

I have an issue. For example. Data from let's say "input 3" goes to column "image 1", because this is a first foreach iteration.

Comment: If you have a new/different question, please ask it via a proper new question. Asking this in the comments is not a good place to ask, as there isn't enough space to provide the proper information, and I'm really the only one who will see it, since I'm the only one who has provided comments.